# Parameter is NULL on DELETE Request

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, servlets

I'm using ajax to send a delete request but I am getting a NULL value. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here is my ajax call

```js
(function() {

    $('#btnDelete').bind('click', function() {

      $.ajax({

        url: '/Project',
        type: 'DELETE',
        cache: false,
        dateType: 'json',
        data: {
          delProjId: $('#projectId').text(),
          nbRandom: Math.random().toString()
        },
        success: function(data) {
          if (data.message[0].error) {
            toastr.error(data.message[0].message);
          } else {
            toastr.success(data.message[0].message);
            console.log('success');
          }
        },
        error: function(request, status, error) {
          toastr.error(error);
        }

      });


    });
```

Here is my post request

```js
protected void doDelete(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

  response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  String delProjId = request.getParameter("delProjId");
  System.out.println("Parm:" + delProjId);


}
```

And the server logs

```js
Parm:null

java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.projectRequest.models.Project.doDelete(Project.java:122)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:210)
```

It currently is set to span element. I tried putting the value in an input field, even adding a JSON.stringify() around the value as I pass it it. I still get the same results, an empty parameter. I see the value on my client and even when I log it prior to executing the ajax call. I'm not sure what is causing the parameter to clear out.

Comment: First of all, it's `dataType`, not `dateType` , and setting it to JSON means the server should **always** return JSON

Comment: Thanks for catching that! However that still didn't resolve the issue. I'm still getting a null value when the servlet is called. And, I am expecting a JSON  output, that's how I'm handling my messages. I'm just not sure why I cannot get the parameter to see the value. I've used this same method before, even when I pass in more than one value and I do not have this problem. Does it have something to do with the DELETE and not a POST?

Comment: Turns out the problem is with the DoDelete. I changed it to a DoPost and I get my parameter value. Why is it that the DoDelete request cannot see my parameter that I am passing in? Can you not pass in parameters on these type of request?

Answer (score 1):

Only **POST** request have parameters as an entity in the request body. You must send it as part of the URL.

See [RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt): "The DELETE method requests that the origin server delete the resource identified by the Request-URI".

You can pass parameters via URI, for example:

http://localhost/?path=/willbedeleted.txt